# saving and retrieving elements from array in chrome.storage.sync

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am making a to-do list pop-up chrome extension. To save the list elements I push them all into an array and save that array to local storage, updating it when changes are made. I currently only push the text value of the original input into the array, and then pass that text back into a new function to create new input elements on the page containing the text from the array. I am having a few problems though:

1. Deleting elements from the array is not working as expected- either the wrong element will be removed from the array, or the element won't be removed from the array at all [initial list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiV79.png) [console log msg 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtWob.png) [list after deleting 2 elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXYuG.png) [console log msg 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJhtc.png)

2. My getList() function is not working as expected either, it won't push the elements from the saved array saved_list in local storage to the empty task_list array that is created when the page loads, and when creating each element in the createListAfterLoad() function, I passed in `i` so it can make that the element id for each new task, but it says that the id is undefined for each of those when created.

Here is my code:

*popup.js*

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#task-form');
const input = document.querySelector('#task-input');
const list_el = document.querySelector('#tasks');
const submitButton = document.querySelector('#submit-button');
let task_list = [];

function inputLength(){
    return input.value.length;
} 

function addTaskClick(){
    if (inputLength() > 0) { //makes sure that an empty input field doesn't create a li
        createList();
    }
}

function addTaskEnter(event) {
    if (inputLength() > 0 && event.which ===13) { //this now looks to see if you hit "enter"/"return"
        //the 13 is the enter key's keycode, this could also be display by event.keyCode === 13
        createList();
    } 
}

function createList() {
    const task = input.value;

    const task_el = document.createElement('div');
    task_el.className = 'task';
    task_el.id = task_list.length;

    const task_complete_el = document.createElement('button');
    task_complete_el.className = 'actions';
    task_complete_el.type = 'submit';
    task_complete_el.id = 'complete-button';

    const complete_button_style = document.createElement('i');
    complete_button_style.classList.add('fa', 'fa-solid', 'fa-check');

    task_complete_el.appendChild(complete_button_style);

    task_el.appendChild(task_complete_el);

    const task_input_el = document.createElement('input');
    task_input_el.className = 'text';
    task_input_el.type = 'text';
    task_input_el.value = task;
    task_input_el.id = task_list.length;
    task_list.push(task_input_el.value);

    task_el.appendChild(task_input_el);

    const task_delete_el = document.createElement('button');
    task_delete_el.className = 'actions';
    task_delete_el.type = 'submit';
    task_delete_el.id = 'delete-button';

    const del_button_style = document.createElement('i');
    del_button_style.classList.add('fa', 'fa-solid', 'fa-times');

    task_delete_el.appendChild(del_button_style);

    task_el.appendChild(task_delete_el);

    list_el.appendChild(task_el);

    saveList(task_list);

    input.value = "";

    task_delete_el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        list_el.removeChild(task_el);
        task_list.splice(Number(task_el.id), 1);
        console.log(task_el.id);
        saveList(task_list)
        console.log(task_list);
    });

    task_complete_el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (task_input_el.style.textDecoration != 'line-through') {
            task_input_el.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            task_list[Number(task_input_el.id)].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            saveList(task_list);
        } else {
            task_input_el.style.textDecoration = 'none';
            task_list[Number(task_input_el.id)].style.textDecoration = 'none';
            saveList(task_list);
        }
    })
}

function createListAfterLoad(text_input, id_number) {
    const task = text_input;

    const task_el = document.createElement('div');
    task_el.className = 'task';
    task_el.id = Number(id_number); 

    const task_complete_el = document.createElement('button');
    task_complete_el.className = 'actions';
    task_complete_el.type = 'submit';
    task_complete_el.id = 'complete-button';

    const complete_button_style = document.createElement('i');
    complete_button_style.classList.add('fa', 'fa-solid', 'fa-check');

    task_complete_el.appendChild(complete_button_style);

    task_el.appendChild(task_complete_el);

    const task_input_el = document.createElement('input');
    task_input_el.className = 'text';
    task_input_el.type = 'text';
    task_input_el.value = task;
    task_input_el.id = Number(id_number);

    task_el.appendChild(task_input_el);

    const task_delete_el = document.createElement('button');
    task_delete_el.className = 'actions';
    task_delete_el.type = 'submit';
    task_delete_el.id = 'delete-button';

    const del_button_style = document.createElement('i');
    del_button_style.classList.add('fa', 'fa-solid', 'fa-times');

    task_delete_el.appendChild(del_button_style);

    task_el.appendChild(task_delete_el);

    list_el.appendChild(task_el);

    input.value = "";

    task_delete_el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        list_el.removeChild(task_el);
        task_list.splice(Number(task_el.id), 1);
        console.log(task_el.id);
        saveList(task_list);
    });

    task_complete_el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (task_input_el.style.textDecoration != 'line-through') {
            task_input_el.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            task_list[Number(task_input_el.id)].style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
            saveList(task_list);
        } else {
            task_input_el.style.textDecoration = 'none';
            task_list[Number(task_input_el.id)].style.textDecoration = 'none';
            saveList(task_list);
        }
    })
}

function saveList(list) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({saved_list: list}, function() {
        console.log('Value is set to ' + list);
      });
}

function getList() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['saved_list'], function(result) {
        result.saved_list.forEach(element => task_list.push(element));

        for (let i = 0; i < result.saved_list.length; i++) {
            createListAfterLoad(result.saved_list[i], i);
        }
    });
}

submitButton.addEventListener("click", addTaskClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addTaskEnter);

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
});

function saveList(list) {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({saved_list: list}, function() {
        console.log('Value is set to ' + list);
      });
}

function getList() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['saved_list'], function(result) {
        result.saved_list.forEach(element => createListAfterLoad(element));
      });
}

submitButton.addEventListener("click", addTaskClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addTaskEnter);

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
});

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getList);
```